# Node.js Setup fails. Where is the log?

Tags: node.js

Busy trying to setup node.js via the windows download on the nodejs website. It seems run along ok right until the end when it hits the "creating shortcurts..." then starts to rollback and get a pretty useless general error.

Are there no log files I can check to see whats going on?

Comment: What is the error when you are trying to install nodejs

Comment: Thats the problem - no specific error. "Setup ended prematurely because of an error" happens right at the end of the process when creating shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

My preferred option is to use the command line msiexec tool [as indicated on WiX's website](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/get_a_log.html):
`msiexec /i MyApplication.msi /l*v MyLogFile.txt`

Another option that I've never used is to edit the registry [as indicated on Microsoft's website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300):

```
To enable Windows Installer logging yourself, open the registry with Regedit.exe and create the following path and keys:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer

Reg_SZ: Logging
Value: voicewarmupx
The letters in the value field can be in any order. Each letter turns on a different logging mode. Each letter's actual function is as follows for MSI version 1.1:
v - Verbose output
o - Out-of-disk-space messages
i - Status messages
c - Initial UI parameters
e - All error messages
w - Non-fatal warnings
a - Start up of actions
r - Action-specific records
m - Out-of-memory or fatal exit information
u - User requests
p - Terminal properties
+ - Append to existing file
! - Flush each line to the log
x - Extra debugging information. The "x" flag is available only on Windows Server 2003 and later operating systems, and on the MSI redistributable version 3.0, and on later versions of the MSI redistributable.

"*" - Wildcard, log all information except for the v and the x option. To include the v and the x option, specify "/l*vx".
Note This should be used only for troubleshooting purposes and should not be left on because it will have adverse effects on system performance and disk space. Each time you use the Add/Remove Programs tool in Control Panel, a new Msi*.log file is created.
```